# I just joined a company and not happy with the position

Tags: new-job, job-change

I am a candidate with 4 years of experience and a Masters in Management and a Masters in Software Engineering. I was recently hired by a company and during recruiting it seemed like a position with responsibilities and something I would love doing. I joined 2 months ago and the situation is very different, it is an entry level position. I was told that I will be reporting to VP, which during first week of job turned to reporting to a manager and after a month I am working under someone who just graduated and have 5 months of work experience, just because they were hired 3 months before me. I don't mind working under someone with less experience, but there is no delegation of work, there is no one I can look up to as a mentor or even talk to. All the work I do remain till the guy who is training me and I never get the chance to talk to the manager or anyone. My initial thought was that he joined before me and has more product experience so he is training me and then I will be working on my own but now I realized that I am under him for good.

The work I am doing is filling in excel sheets, putting in some coding scripts, and literally doing anything the guy doesn't have time to do. There is no learning involved and I couldn't sleep the whole night thinking about what I got myself into. Before this job I worked for 3 years pretty much managing a whole team and most recently in my 6 months internship as a Product Owner I helped rolling out two products from scratch where I was managing all the stakeholders including developers and designers, but here I am working literally as an assistant to someone doing tasks involving no learning. I don't want to quit but I feel miserable. I have higher goals for me, I wanted to work with someone I can learn a lot from.

I want to know who shall I talk to ? what shall I do?

Comment: "Before this job I worked for 3 years pretty much managing a whole team and most recently in my 6 months internship as a Product Owner I helped rolling out two products from scratch where I was managing all the stakeholders including developers and designers" Was your current employer aware of this before they extended their offer to you? What representations about your position did your current employer make to you so that they got you to accept? It's either a case of miscommunication of expectations or non-communication of expectations leading to miscommunication of expectations.

Comment: "I don't want to quit but I feel miserable. I have higher goals for me, I wanted to work with someone I can learn a lot from." It looks like you want to have your cake i.e. "I don't want to quit" and you want to have it, too i.e. "I have higher goals for me, I wanted to work with someone I can learn a lot from." Under the current setup, you can't have it both ways - it is impossible for you to have it both ways - and you most probably already know it. Are you trying to have it both ways?

Comment: You had 3 years of experience in your previous job, and you accepted a 6month internship after that ? 

What is the level of the position you have accepted right now ?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you not want to quit?
This job is clearly not a good fit for you, and whilst the best solution would be to change roles within the company to something ideal for you, I suspect that finding another job would be considerably more feasible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bring up being misled about my job role during the interview period?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11908/how-do-i-bring-up-being-misled-about-my-job-role-during-the-interview-period)

Comment: Also [Actual work is different than expected - decision to be made](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28254/actual-work-is-different-than-expected-decision-to-be-made)

Comment: And career advice is off topic, voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend finding the manager in charge of the project(s) or the head of the department or someone similar, schedule a meeting with them and discuss these concerns.

Based on what he/she has to say about your situation, you can then decide what to do about this. This can include of course quitting from that company since, from what you say, it's kind of a regressive career move for you if the situation doesn't change.

An important mention is to be very calm and respectful in this discussion, don't get angry or assign any blame, even if it is a frustrating situation for you. Approaching this calmly significantly increases the odds of a more happy ending.